# Is it possible to embed couchdb into python app and deploy as one exe in windows server?

Tags: python, windows, couchdb, fastapi

Actually, I have an application with backend Database to be deployed in one of the windows server. The database is couchdb and application is built using FastAPI with Jinja templating for front end.

I got to know that we can make one batch file to install all the dependency and deploy the application, but is there any way to embed the couchdb with the application?

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Comment: It is to make the application as one bundle like one-click install.

Comment: "one-click install" sounds like end user application whereas you tech stack is server application. For server application a good approach to reliable deployment is docker / docker-compose.